# Function returns variable instead of the assigned value of the variable

Tags: python

I have a rather simple code in Python (see below), but cannot figure out why the "selection" variable does not return the assigned global value of the variable instead of the variable in the function. So for example, if I run the function "drink_coffee", the returned value should be "cappuccino" when I select "a". Instead, it returns "a". But if I print "a" from within the function it returns "cappuccino". Any ideas what I am missing?

```
a = 'cappuccino'
b = 'espresso'
c = 'latte'


def drink_coffee():
    '''Returns the coffee the user would like to drink'''
    global a, b, c
    selection = input("What would you like to drink? A: cappuccino, B: espresso, C:latte? ").lower()
    print(selection)
    print(a)
    return selection
```

drink_coffee()

Comment: Use a dictionary: `{'a': 'cappuccino', 'b': …}`! And BTW you don't need `global` if you just read values.

Comment: Hi, and maybe one of the problems is that you use the input as a new var ( selection ) and it returns "string" ( <class 'str'> ) not a global variable

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a string whose contents are the letter `a` and a variable called a that contains some content.

In your code you assign the user input to the variable `selection` which will contain whatever string the user types in.

I think what you want here is to store your letter-to-drink mappings in a dictionary. It might look something like this:

```
drink_mappings = { "a" : 'cappuccino',
                   "b" : 'espresso',
                   "c" : 'latte' }
```

Then when the user provides a string of a, b or c - you can use your `drink_mappings` dictionary to resolve and return the mapped drink name:

e.g.

```
def drink_coffee():
    '''Returns the coffee the user would like to drink'''
    
    selection = input("What would you like to drink? A: cappuccino, B: espresso, C:latte? ").lower()
    print(drink_mappings.get(selection, "Nothing") )
    print(a)
    return drink_mappings.get(selection, "Nothing")
```

This should give you the behaviour you want. Generally speaking though, you can't normally directly reference a variable name using a string value entered via user input. It is possible, using some introspection code though - but this probably isn't the best use for that kind of thing. For interest, here's how that might work though:

```
def drink_coffee():
'''Returns the coffee the user would like to drink'''
global a, b, c
selection = input("What would you like to drink? A: cappuccino, B: espresso, C:latte? ").lower()
print(selection)
print(a)
return globals()[selection]
```

Which uses the `globals()` dictionary holding all the currently active global variables and allows you to reference them by a string that matches their name. There's a similar built-in dictionary called `locals()` that does a similar thing, if you're not into using global variables.

But this is a really weird thing to do, and people would squint with incredulity if they saw it for a use-case like this. For example, any user running this code could access any variable or function currently active by typing in its name. This would raise some serious security issues and would be a considered a pretty big no-no.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Appreciate the detailed answer.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved by @Thomas Kimber